# Executing Process not working

Tags: c#, .net, service, process

**The situation:**

> I want to modify the folder quotas on my FileServer through a process executing dirquota.exe

**The Problem:**

> The Process being executed gives no result at all

**So Far:**

> I've redirected the process and arguments being executed on my FileServer to take a closer look what's happening exactly on the serverside.
>   
>   **The executed process gave no exception** and everything went just fine, it seemed..
>   When looking at the current folder quota's on my FileServer nothing has changed..
> I decided to copy paste my arguments in a CMD.exe on the server, then it all went fine...
>   
>  I cannot figure why it is not working on my FileServer, probably somthing simple but I need some help here

**Important Info:**

> I'm installing a Windows Service on my FileServer and calling the Method through SOUPUI (This is all working fine).
>   
>   
>   The installed service is running as a Domain admin and has all the required rights to perform these actions

**The Class**

```
public class Quota
    {
        public string FolderLocation;
        public int SizeInMB;
        public string FileServerName;
    }
```

**The Method**

```
public string SetFolderQuota(Quota quota)
        {
            Process QuotaProcess = new Process();

            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;            
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + "dirquota Quota Add /PATH:" + '"' + quota.FolderLocation + '"' + " /Limit:" + quota.SizeInMB + "mb" + " /remote:" + quota.FileServerName;

            try
            {                
                QuotaProcess.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                return Ex.Message;
            }

            return "Correctly Executed: " + QuotaProcess.StartInfo.FileName + QuotaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments;
        }
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the full path to dirquota in your argument? It may be that it can't find the dirquota (though probably unlikely).

Comment: Tried that too, same result. good thinking though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found The Problem**

> dirquota.exe is redirected using Windows-on Windows 64-bit redirection. What's happening is that my launch request (from a 32-bit process) is being redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\dirquota.exe. Since there's no 32-bit version of this particular executable on 64-bit installs, the launch fails. To bypass this process and allow my 32-bit process to access the native (64-bit) path, I have to reference %windir%\sysnative instead

**The Code**

```
 public string SetFolderQuota(Quota quota)
        {

            string FileLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),@"sysnative\dirquota.exe");

            Process QuotaProcess = new Process();

            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.FileName = FileLocation;
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            QuotaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " Quota Add /PATH:" + '"' + quota.FolderLocation + '"' + " /Limit:" + quota.SizeInMB + "mb" + " /remote:" + quota.FileServerName;

            try
            {                
                QuotaProcess.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                return Ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + "FileLocation: " + FileLocation;
            }

            return "Correctly Executed: " + QuotaProcess.StartInfo.FileName + QuotaProcess.StartInfo.Arguments;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best if you can redirect the output of Process to a log file and see what is the actual exception..

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo
{ 
   CreateNoWindow = false,
   UseShellExecute = false, 
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   FileName = @"cmd.exe",
   Arguments = "/C " + "dirquota Quota Add /PATH:" + '"' + quota.FolderLocation + '"' + " /Limit:" + quota.SizeInMB + "mb" + " /remote:" + quota.FileServerName
};

Process p = Process.Start(process);
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Log the value of output to get the exact exception caused by execution of this command

Comment: There is no exception... I've tried that and the response is empty

Comment: You sure that the account through which the service is running is a System Administrator or member of Administrator group?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem, see my answer above